# Representing number, where digits are cubes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion, python

Let $n$ is integer and we want to express it in terms of $10$ as $$n=R^3_k10^k+R^3_{k-1}10^{k-1} \cdots+ R^3_0$$ where $R_i\in \{\pm0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\ldots,\pm9\}$

Example : $37= 1^3\times10+3^3$

Algorithms: Let $$
n = Q_0 \cdot 10+R^3_0,
$$

where $ |R_0| <  10$. Then, we can in turn represent

$$
Q_0 = Q_1 \cdot 10 + R^3_1,
$$

where $ |R_1| <  10 $, and so on, so we can find $R_0, R_1, \dots$ with consecutive division by $10$ and taking remainders.

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        n&=Q_0\cdot 10+R^3_0 \\
        Q_0&= Q_1\cdot 10+R^3_1 \\
        Q_1&= Q_2\cdot 10+R^3_2 \\
       \vdots &=\quad \vdots\\
       Q_{k-2} &= Q_{k-1}\cdot 10+R^3_{k-1}\\
       Q_{k-1} &= 0\cdot f + R^3_{k}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

where $R_i\in \{\pm0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\ldots,\pm9\}$

Hence, $n=(R^3_k,R^3_{k-1}, \cdots, R^3_0)_{10}\quad \text{or simply} \quad [R_k,R_{k-1}, \cdots, R_0]$

Note: For each $Q$ there are $R^3$ and $-R^3_*$ such that $Q\equiv R^3\equiv -R^3_*\pmod{10}$

Example:  \begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}531&=2^3\times 10^2+(-3)^3\times 10+1^3\\
&=(2^3,-3^3,1^3)_{10}\\
&=[2,-3,1]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

here representation is not unique. for example

\begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}531
&=(2^3,-3^3,1^3)_{10}\\
&=(1^3,-2^3,-1^3,-4^3,-9^3)_{10}\\
&=[1,-2,-1,-4,-9]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Define function $D(n)$, calculate minimal degree to represent $n$ in terms of $10$ where coefficients are cube number less than $10^3$ and greater than $-10^3$

so $D(531)=2$ because we can express $531=2\times 10^2+(-3)^3\times 10+1^3$ have degree $2$ and smallest representation.

> Question: Is there any approach to calculate $D(n)$ in fastest way? if yes, what is it?

---

*Question has already been asked on MathOverflow but no one answers link : https://mathoverflow.net/q/454193/149083
I have not been able to complete program which verify the shortest representation. How to solve loop problem in code. If you make please share your code. thank you in advanced. Here what I attempt in code,*

```
def d2(y):
    res = []
    for p in range(15):
        if y > 0:
            if y%10 == 0:
                k = y%10
                res.append(k)
                y = (y-k**3)//10
            elif y%10 == 1:
                k = y%10
                res.append(k)
                y = (y-k**3)//10
            elif y%10 == 2:
                k = 10 - y%10
                res.append(k)
                y = (y-k**3)//10
            elif y%10 == 3:
                k = 10 - y%10
                res.append(k)
                y = (y-k**3)//10
            elif y%10 == 4:
                k = y%10
                res.append(k)
                y = (y-k**3)//10
            elif y%10 == 5:
                k = y%10
                res.append(k)
                y = (y-k**3)//10
            elif y%10 == 6:
                k = y%10
                res.append(k)
                y = (y-k**3)//10
            elif y%10 == 7:
                k = 10 - y%10
                res.append(k)
                y = (y-k**3)//10
            elif y%10 == 8:
                k = 10 - y%10
                res.append(k)
                y = (y-k**3)//10
            elif y%10 == 9:
                k = y%10
                res.append(k)
                y = (y-k**3)//10
        elif y < 0:
            if y%10 == 0:
                k = y%10
                res.append(k)
                y = (y-k**3)//10
            elif y%10 == 9:
                res.append(-1)
                y = (y+1**3)//10
            elif y%10 == 8:
                res.append(-8)
                y = (y+8**3)//10
            elif y%10 == 7:
                res.append(-7)
                y = (y+7**3)//10
            elif y%10 == 6:
                res.append(-4)
                y = (y+4**3)//10
            elif y%10 == 5:
                res.append(-5)
                y = (y+5**3)//10
            elif y%10 == 4:
                res.append(-6)
                y = (y+6**3)//10
            elif y%10 == 3:
                res.append(-3)
                y = (y+3**3)//10
            elif y%10 == 2:
                res.append(-2)
                y = (y+2**3)//10
            elif y%10 == 1:
                res.append(-9)
                y = (y+9**3)//10
        if y == 0:
            break
    if len(res[::-1]) == 15:
        return("not get, stuck in a loop, try another number")
    else :
        return res[::-1]

for i in range(1000,1100):
    print(i,d2(i),"\n")

>>> output 

1000 [1, 0, 0, 0] 

1001 [1, 0, 0, 1] 

1002 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1003 [1, 1, -5, 6, 7] 

1004 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1005 [2, 2, 5] 

1006 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1007 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1008 [1, 0, 0, 2] 

1009 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1010 [1, 0, 1, 0] 

1011 [1, 0, 1, 1] 

1012 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1013 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1014 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1015 [-4, 9, 5] 

1016 [2, 0, 6] 

1017 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1018 [1, 0, 1, 2] 

1019 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1020 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1021 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1022 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1023 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1024 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1025 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1026 [2, 1, 6] 

1027 [1, 0, 0, 3] 

1028 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1029 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1030 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1031 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1032 [-1, 3, -6, 8, 8] 

1033 [-1, -1, 5, -6, 9, 7] 

1034 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1035 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1036 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1037 [1, 0, 1, 3] 

1038 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1039 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1040 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1041 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1042 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1043 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1044 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1045 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1046 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1047 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1048 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1049 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1050 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1051 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1052 [-1, 4, 8] 

1053 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1054 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1055 [1, 0, -5, 7, 5] 

1056 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1057 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1058 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1059 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1060 [-1, -1, 6, 0] 

1061 [-1, -1, 6, 1] 

1062 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1063 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1064 [1, 0, 0, 4] 

1065 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1066 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1067 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1068 [-1, -1, 6, 2] 

1069 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1070 [2, 3, 0] 

1071 [2, 3, 1] 

1072 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1073 [-3, 7, 7] 

1074 [1, 0, 1, 4] 

1075 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1076 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1077 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1078 [2, 3, 2] 

1079 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1080 [1, 0, 2, 0] 

1081 [1, 0, 2, 1] 

1082 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1083 [1, 4, 7] 

1084 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1085 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1086 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1087 [-1, -1, 6, 3] 

1088 [1, 0, 2, 2] 

1089 [-1, -2, 6, 9] 

1090 [-2, 5, -8, 9, 0] 

1091 [-2, 5, -8, 9, 1] 

1092 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1093 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1094 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1095 not get, stuck in a loop, try another number 

1096 [2, 2, 6] 

1097 [2, 3, 3] 

1098 [-2, 5, -8, 9, 2] 

1099 [1, 3, 9]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to compute $D(n)$ is as follows:

From right to left, number the digits of a number as 0, 1, 2, ...

We work from right to left.  At step $i$, we have already represented digits 0, 1, $\dots$, $i-1$ of $n$ with a vector $f$ of digits from the set 0, $(\pm 1)^3$, $\dots$, $(\pm 9)^3$, and we wish to represent the digits at and to the left of the digit $i$ in $n$.  The vector $f$ may have generated some carries into digit $i$, and we need to take care of those as well.

At step $i$, we have a list of pairs $(f, n')$, each consisting of a vector $f=(f_{i-1},\dots,f_0)$ of already generated output digits together with the number $n'$ which we still need to express.  For each pair in the list, we try all possible candidates (either one or two) for the output digit $f_i$ which give the correct result modulo 10.  Then, we generate new pairs $((f_i, f_{i-1}, \dots, f_0), (n'-f_i)/10)$ and add them to the list for step $i+1$. If a pair containing $(n'-f_i)/10$ is already in the list, we can either do nothing or replace it with the new pair.

At step 0, the list is initialized with $(\epsilon, n)$, where $\epsilon$ is the empty vector and $n$ is the number we wish to express.  We stop at the earliest step when a pair $(f, n')$ with $n'=0$ is in the list and output $f$.

This algorithm does not result in exponential blowup because the carries into digit $i$ are bounded: the generated carries must amount to a sum of strictly less than
$$
\sum_{j>0} \frac{9^3}{10^j}=81
$$
and similarly the carries must strictly exceed $-81$.  So, the possible values for $n'$ at each step are confined to an interval of length less than $2\cdot 81=162$, meaning that there are never more than 162 entries in the list at any step.

Here is an implementation in Python 3.

```
import sys

n = int(sys.argv[1])

digits = [(i, i ** 3) for i in range(-9, 10)]

reps = {n : []}

max_count = 1

while 0 not in reps:
    reps_next = {}
    for remdr, rep in reps.items():
        for dig_name, dig_val in digits:
            if dig_val % 10 == remdr % 10:
                reps_next[(remdr - dig_val) // 10] = [dig_name] + rep
    reps = reps_next
    max_count = max(max_count, len(reps))

print('Maximum alternative count:', max_count)
print('Representation:', *(digit for digit in reps[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks, how to use this code, when I plot it, gives, ```invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-f'```

Comment: Try changing the line `n = int(sys.argv[1])` to `n = 345`, where 345 should be replaced by the number you wish to express.